# Duplicate Composition (PS Layer) in After Effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects

I have imported a Photoshop CC 2015.1 document into After Effects CC 2015.1.

I have animated one of the layers. I want to create an alternate animation for the same layer. When I duplicate the layer, either with Copy/Paste or with Edit > Duplicate, then work on the copy, my changes happen to both copies.

How can I duplicate the layer and turn it into a completely independent composition?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check out this post on the adobe site [composition duplicate](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/756076?start=0&tstart=0) by Jon-M-Spesr, In Windows Project Panel click on the composition you wish to duplicate and hit <Ctrl D>,  Rename the composition.

Answer (score 1):

As per @AndrewH’s comment and some other things I found online, the trick is to Duplicate the composition **in the Project panel**, not in the Timeline.